# Load specific CSS asynchronously and when it is loaded remove waiting message

Tags: javascript, html, css, asynchronous

To improve speed and quickly show something to the user. I am trying to block render blocking css and load it using some js code asynchronously. I have only one css on the page which maintains the design of the complete page. I want to show some **please wait** message to the user until this css file load is not complete.

As soon as the load of this CSS file is complete, remove this message. No matter whether all other resources loading is completed or not.

I am trying to use the following js code as suggested by google ([Optimize CSS Delivery](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery#example)) to load css file:

```
<script>
  var cb = function() {
    var l = document.createElement('link'); l.rel = 'stylesheet';
    l.href = 'small.css';
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
  };
  var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
  if (raf) raf(cb);
  else window.addEventListener('load', cb);
</script>
```

I have tried the following code to show please wait for the message:

```
<script>
        document.onreadystatechange = function () {
            var state = document.readyState
            if (state == 'complete') {
                document.getElementById('interactive');
                document.getElementById('load').style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

But this code, blocks the page until all resources are not downloaded be it image, js or css. But I just want it to happen on a specific CSS file to avoid [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content)

Answer (score 3):

You could define a preloader in your default CSS (the one which is going to load every time):

```
#load {
   display: block;
}
```

And in the CSS you want to fetch (`small.css`), you could override the definition:

```
#load {
   display: none;
}
```

After the file loads, the loader would also hide thanks to the definition override.

Comment: Wow, so elegant and simple. Never thought of it, was going too complex :D

Answer (score 1):

if you are allowed to use jquery then

```
    $.get(url, function(){
                $('<link>', {rel:'stylesheet', type:'text/css', 'href':url}).appendTo('head');
            });
        })
    ).then(function(){
       //your callback function
  }
```